# ¿Como guardar datos en tabla relacionada con otra en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

Tengo un modelo llamado Usuario que puede tomar varios roles, como puede ser un Administrador, un Supervisor, un maestro, en fin. Por ende para cada uno de los roles creo otras entidades mas que estarán relacionadas con el modelo Usuario. Ahora, cree un formulario para poder guardar un Administrador, pero aquí es donde me surge la duda

¿Como puedo guardar un Administrador con los datos básicos de usuario y que haga la inserción en Usuario y que lo relacione en usuario? Dejo el codigo de las migraciones de cada una de las entidades.

**Entidad Usuario/User**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('firstname');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->enum('id_type',['Cedula','Cedula extrangera','Tarjeta de identidad']);
            $table->string('id_number')->unique();
            $table->string('password');

            //Optional
            $table-enum('net',['Pre-Juvenil','Juvenil','Universitaria','Ejecutiva','Matrimonios menores','Matrimonio mayores'])->nullable();
            $table-enum('ministerial_state',['Lider','Estudiante ADO','Graduado no lanzado'])->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->string('telephone')->nullable();
            $table->string('cellphone')->nullable();
            $table->date('birthday')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
        });
    }
```

**Entidad Administrador/Administrator**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('administrators', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
```

Comment: No te convendría analizar y mejorar tu DER? definir mejor usuario (analizar si necesitas crear otra entidad admin o agregar un rol a usuario). En caso de ser necesario crear la entidad admin, lo mas prolijo seria crear las otras entidades ( supervisor, maestro,etc)

Comment: Si claro yo cree las entidades y todas extienden de usuario, como dije el usuario que puede ser una persona comun y corriente puede tomar 1 o mas roles en este caso de supervisor, maestro, etc

Answer (score 1):

Asi es como lo hago

```
function almacenar(Request $request) {
    $data=$request->all();//obtengo las variables
    $this->modelUsuario->setVariables($data);//Asigno las variables necesarias
    $bool=$this->modelUsuario->save();//return true o false
    if($bool){
      $idUsuario=$this->modelUsuario->id; //considerando que id es primary key del modelo
      $this->modelAdministrador->setIdAdministrador($idUsuario);//Asigno la variable Idusuario 
      $this->modelAdministrador->setVariables($data);//Asigno las variables necesarias
      $boolAdministrador= $this->modelAdministrador->save();
    }
  return  $boolAdministrador;
}
```

Espero que te sirva  :D

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio!